# Why is `gradlew buildDebug` not calling `assemble` but `gradlew build` is?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have an Android project and I was running the following code to assemble an `apk`:

```
./gradlew app:assembleDebug
```

or this if I wanted a release version

```
./gradlew app:assembleRelease
```

I realized that Unit Tests were not being executed. After digging a little I found out that `build` depends on `assemble` and also on `test` and `check`.

When I run

```
./gradlew app:build
```

I can see both debug and release apk generated in the the `output` folder.
However if I run

```
./gradlew app:buildDebug
```

the `output` folder contains no apk files. I can see that `assemble` was not called when I specified the build type.

Any idea why this is?
How can I use gradle to build, run tests and generate an apk in one command for a specific build type?